# Безопасность сервера,apache 2.4 на ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, сервер, веб-сервер, apache2.4

Подскажите направление по защите своего сервера, на котором разместил сайт.
К примеру.
Написал сайт, установил на удаленный сервер Ubuntu 18.04, Apach 2.4.
Я не хотел бы к примеру видеть по запросу url, структуру моего каталога, его легко увидеть в файле js, так как он оттуда берет данные по запросу, поэтому в файле .htaccess указал доступ к определенным участкам сайта.

Я не сталкивался с таким, и понятия не имею куда смотреть,что бы я был уверен в безопасности сайта и что мою структуру не просмотрят и не выкачают файлы,жалко что писал сервис 3 месяца,а кто-то выкачает.

Прошу просто указать направление)

Comment: Начни копать в сторону `fail2ban`.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0